# Ability to hook context aware object factory when unmarshalling objects with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jaxb

I am trying to unmarshall (XMl -> POJO) an object using JAXB.

XML:

```
<my_object>
   <uniqueName>foo</uniqueName>
   <propertyX>blah</propertyX>
</my_object>
```

Java class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="my_object")
class MyObject {
   private String uniqueName;
   private String propertyX;

   // getters, setters omitted
}
```

Unmarshalling works, however in some cases I would like to make the unmarshaller to use an object which is created by me, based on the `uniqueName`. Something like this (pseudo code):

```
// parse the uniqueName field first
MyObject template = myObjectDAO.loadByName(uniqueName); // result can be null
if (template == null) {
   template = new MyObject();
   template.setUniqueName(uniqueName);
}
// carry on with other fields
```

Currently I have solved this by:

1. Always using the default unmarshaller behaviour (letting JAXB to create the template by using public no args constructor) and parsing all fields.
2. Attempting to load the object by `uniqueName` and if object exists - copying over all fields using `BeanUtils.copyProperties(unmarshalled, loaded)`.

The above works but is sub-optimal.

Questions:

- Is there a way to solve this using standard JAXB techniques?
- If not, would it be possible to solve this if the `uniqueName` was known in advance (before unmarshalling)?

p.s. `uniqueName` is **not** an identifier (at least in terms of Hibernate) so using JAXB-Hibernate integration most likely won't work.